# Postgresql drop role command not working

Tags: command-line, 16.04, postgresql, sql

drop role command not working in my postgresql 11. I can't delete the role named 'ckdev' .

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ckdev |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres-# drop role ckdev
postgres-# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ckdev |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `;` at the end of sql command?

```
drop role ckdev;
```

Comment: it is syntax error, `;` is missing, and postgres didn't talk when there is errors